# heterogeneous containers and handle objects

Tags: c++

I have a inheritance hierarchy. My base class is an abstract class.

```
      class A{};
      class B : public A{};
      class C : public A{};
      class D : public A{};
      class E : public A{};
```

I wish to send objects from the child classes B, C, D, E to a vector container.

I know that I can create a Handle class in order to do this. Can somebody recommend a good tutorial or article that I can read that will show me how to do this?

I know that I can use boost::any as a solution, however I would like to try solving this using Handle classes.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to come up with something better than std::shared_ptr<A>

Comment: What does "send objects from the child classes B, C, D, E to a vector container" exactly means? I mean, do you just want to do an std::vector<A*> or something else?

Comment: Do you want the container to own the objects? In other words, when you delete the container do you want the objects to be deleted as well? Or are the objects owned elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a handle or `boost::any`, pointers to `A` are already the best "handle" in this situation. So what you want is a `vector` containing `A*`, or better, smart pointers.

Which smart pointer depends on the life cycle of the objects in question. If you need the contained objects to have lifetimes that are not tied to the lifetime of the container (i.e. the container does not own the contained objects, but merely references them), then `shared_ptr<A>` is your best option.

On the other hand, there is an overhead attached to `shared_ptr`, so in the case where the lifetime of your objects are encompassed by the lifetime of the container, and they are only used by retrieving them from the container (i.e. the container owns the contained objects), `unique_ptr<A>` is probably your best choice.

(If your compiler doesn't support `unique_ptr` yet, then you might consider looking into the Boost pointer container library, which provides standard containers that manage the lifetime of the contained objects.)

In short, you should use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`, depending on the life cycle of the objects in question.

Answer (score 0):

As someone has mentioned, `std::vector<shared_ptr<A> >` is probably the easiest option.  Alternatively, boost::variant is something you could look at, but it doesn't make sense in this case, where all classes have common parent.  Don't forget to add a virtual destructor to A, if you actually plan to have any data members in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

My revised answer!

```
      class A{};
      class B : public A{};
      class C : public A{};
      class D : public A{};
      class E : public A{};
```

Classes B,C,D and E have class A as a common base class. Simply define your container to hold pointers to this base Class A. Next, you store a derived class object in the container. Do this by storing the objects address as an element in the container.You can access objects in the container via polymorphic use of pointers of type A. Check out the virtual constructor idiom.

Comment: This is usually a bad idea, because you have to manually manage the lifetime of objects in the vector. I suggest using a smart pointer like `shared_ptr<>` if possible instead of raw pointers